# Serialize Json file with separate list and object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a JSON file with 2 object-array of strings,and a string. and I need to serialize it, so I will have the ability to have 2 different object, that each contains 1 object from the JSON file, or like list that the first or the last member if the string will be the single string.

I have tried solutions that were here, but it gave me errors.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("Licensce.json")) {
    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
    List<string> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
}
```

The Json file is like this:

```
{
 "UsbDevices": [
     "SA",
     "SB",
     "SC",
     "SE2",
     "SF",
     "M",
 ] 
 "DeviceConnectivityExperationDateTime" : "2020-12-30"
}
```

The error was:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: You have tried this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json)` however, its obvious the json isn't a list of string. Why don't you just desieralize to a concrete class like all the examples show, anyway i am closing this as too broad, as there are just way too many examples of how to do this on stackoverflow and the internet

Comment: I don't know if it is because of typo, but be aware that your Json file structure is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your json format or compare with below format

```
 var json = @"{
               'UsbDevices': [
                            'SA',
                            'SB',
                            'SC',
                            'SE2',
                            'SF',
                            'M'],
               'DeviceConnectivityExperationDateTime' : '2020-12-30'
              }";                
                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);           
        }

public class Data
{
   public Data()
   {
      this.UsbDevices = new List<string>();
   }
   public List<string> UsbDevices { get; set; }
   public string DeviceConnectivityExperationDateTime { get; set; }
 }
```